# Paypal SOAP API using python

Tags: python, soap, paypal, wsdl

I need to implement paypal payment feature using their SOAP api. My programming language is python.

I have downloaded wsdl and xsd files from paypal and saved in my local server directory.

When i tried to parse wsdl using suds my pc hanged on.

```
from suds.client import Client
url ='http://127.0.0.1:8003/static/paypal/wsdl/sandbox/PayPalSvc.wsdl'
client = Client(url)
```

After running few minutes i was able to recover the hangout and here is the exception stack i got from my console.

```
.................................................................
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.open_imports(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 563, in download
    return self.schema.instance(root, url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 397, in instance
    return Schema(root, baseurl, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 225, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 250, in build
    self.children = BasicFactory.build(self.root, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 774, in build
    child = cls.create(node, schema)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 756, in create
    return fn(schema, root)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 518, in __init__
    SchemaObject.__init__(self, schema, root)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/sxbase.py", line 95, in __init__
```

I am stuck with it. It will be very much helpful and appreciated if anyone help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: At last this patch: https://fedorahosted.org/suds/attachment/ticket/239/recurselevel-schema.py.patch seem to work :)